# Should I do detrending or smoothing first?

Tags: time-series, trend, smoothing, data-preprocessing

Does it matter which one I perform first? If yes, why?

Might be a simple question, yet I could not find an answer anywhere else.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of this exercise and tell us what techniques you have in mind both for detrending and smoothing?  Some techniques interact well with each other and others do not, suggesting that reasonable people may provide diametrically opposite answers depending on what assumptions are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: none of the above. Detrend the data, if your analysis technique requires detrended data, but don't smooth. Building on @whuber’s insightful comment below, I would again emphasize “analyze”: if you’re exploring and looking for an idea, go ahead and smooth or whatever inspires you, but if you intend to do something that has diagnostics or analyzes, don’t smooth. Also I am assuming Time series here. People also smooth images and Laplace Smooth sparse contingency tables. (The latter is a good idea.)

It's almost always a mistake to analyze smoothed data. Smoothing can introduce false correlations, change phases, and cause information leaks, among other problems. I think there's a strange attraction, that we all experience at some point, to smooth or to categorize noisy continuous data. It feels like it makes things more precise, but it does not.

True experts who know exactly what they're doing might be able to get away with it under the right circumstances, but I'd highly recommend against it. (@whuber didn't shut the question down, and as always in these forums, I defer to more experienced judgement, but I would still argue that it's tricky and often of little benefit even if done right.)

In general, the techniques you'd use on time series either account for noise or even explicitly model it (State Space methods, for example). Why blur -- which is what smoothing is essentially doing -- your data before working with it?

For visualization purposes, it can be handy to run a smoothed "trend" line through the data to help focus a viewer away from extreme noise, but as a step before analysis...

Again, State Space methods (Kalman methods) can explicitly model trends and noise. In which case you'd neither detrend nor smooth. Perhaps you would find them useful?

[ORIGINAL] In my understanding, smoothing should really only be done as the last step, and only for display. Trying to analyze smoothed data is full of pitfalls.

Detrending can be accomplished in a couple of ways, which were you going to use?

What is your goal?

Comment: The goal would be to reduce the noise in the data before using it to train some model. I thought of just using a rolling mean, but I could choose any method. I just want to keep it as simple as possible when it comes to pre-processing for the moment.

Comment: @whuber seems to think that smoothing might be appropriate, so there's a good chance it is. I would strongly recommend against it. It screws up phase and other aspects of your data, and if you naively do a centered running mean, you will create a leak in your data that will swcrew up forecasting.

Comment: Please don't read too much into my comments.  (1) I didn't put the thread on hold because you had already provided a thoughtful answer.  (2) However, I still find both the question and your answer to be vague because neither clearly describes the circumstances: are we talking about statistical procedures in general, or only time series analysis (or some other narrower domain), and what are we trying to achieve with detrending or smoothing?  For instance, if the purpose is an exploration to develop hypotheses, we should strongly favor approaches that (robustly) smooth and generalize the data.